# Best software to use for editing audiobooks?

Tags: audiobook, wave-editor

I do audiobook editing for a local library. I am using sound forge currently. Are there any recommendations for other editors? I get a lot of pops and lip smacking. It seems to take forever to finish.

Answer (score 1):

This post may be insightful: http://www.stavrosound.com/blog/wordpress/2012/02/the-rice-crispies-mix-snap-crackle-pop/

The deal is, with what you mention, is that it really doesn't matter what software tool you use at all - there is no magic bullet to this stuff.  it's about rolling up your sleeves and getting dirty like how professional dialogue editors for film/tv do (the above post goes into details).  Sometimes plugins from Waves or iZotope can help but it's like that old phrase of "the tools always change but the process stays the same".

Answer (score 1):

Who is recording them? 
You should try to minimize pops and smacks in the recording phase. Of course some speakers, older people especially, are more prone to making extra cicks and smacks, but you should maybe record from a little bit further away and keep the speakers hydrated with a jug of water etc.
Take enough breaks.

The audiobook guys usually are very sensitive about background noise and s/n-ratio. In many cases the speaker records himself, at least in the lower budget audiobooks.

I'm not too familiar with Sound Forge, but i think that this problem should be at the recording session. It doesn't matter which software you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit out all sorts of noises with iZotope RX 2 and e.g. Adobe Audition's spectral editor, but that'll take ages and is not worth it, if there are constant mouth noises. Follow Miska Seppa's advice and try to solve the problems as well as you can during recording and minimize the amount of editing. Spectral editors and "audio repair" tools are nice for occasional fixes, but you don't want to rely on them and you don't want to spend your time on editing problems that could be solved and minimized during recording.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful piece of software.

![http://www.dolphinmusic.co.uk/shop_image/product/8367-se-electronics-pop--large.jpg][1]